# Scrutinize Dropbox activity

Tags: dropbox

When using dropbox, is there a command from terminal (mint or ubuntu preferably) that shows which files dropbox is syncing?

Up to now I just get the blue icon that Dropbox is doing something, but I would to see what it is exactly doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
dropbox status
```

is what you can put in terminal to see the status of dropbox

also, this may help https://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli